# How to Count Distinct on Case Insensitive Column using JPA and Criteria API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

How can I do the following using the JPA criteria API?

`select count(distinct LOWER(column)) from table`

This is working without the `LOWER(column)` but not producing the expected result.

But with `LOWER(column)`, Hibernate is throwing `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '('`.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Use Native query, JPQL don't support that.

Comment: @Rono Can I use Native query with Criteria API, since I have some optional parameters I want to build with the query.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following raw query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col_lower) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT LOWER(column) AS col_lower
    FROM yourTable
) t;
```

I then tried to think of a way to express this using JPQL, but JPQL only supports subqueries in the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clauses.  So, you might need to use either a raw query here or maybe the Criteria API.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```java
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<String> cq = cb.createQuery(String.class);
        Root<Table> r = cq.from(Table.class);
        cq.select(cb.lower(r.get(Table_.column))).distinct(true);
        TypedQuery<String> query = em.createQuery(cq);
        
        Long counter = query.getResultList().size();
```